# @Autowired custom ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource in @Controller

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, internationalization, autowired

I've built an application composed of angularJs for the client side and spring MVC for the backend side. My purpose is to expose my language properties to the client side, so that I can use them in my JS files. To do that, I've used the library angular-translate.min.js and followed thoses instructions:
(https://gist.github.com/rvillars/6422287).

Basically the idea is to create a custom class which extends from ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource, and override getAllProperties(Locale locale) method. Then, injecting that custom class in a @controller, which will return the list of properties in a Json format to the client.
So far my issue is that I haven't been able to autowired my custom class extending ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource, in my @controller. My app always crashing during the deployment phase with "No qualifying bean of type CustomResourceBundleMessageSource".

My environment:
Spring MVC 3.2.3
Angular JS

Please find the code:

Controller class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/messageBundle")
public class SerializableMessageBundleController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource;


    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public Properties list(@RequestParam String lang) {
        return messageSource.getAllProperties(new Locale(lang));
    }
```

Custom message source:

```
public class CustomResourceBundleMessageSource extends ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource  {

     public Properties getAllProperties(Locale locale) {
            clearCacheIncludingAncestors();
            PropertiesHolder propertiesHolder = getMergedProperties(locale);
            Properties properties = propertiesHolder.getProperties();

            return properties;
        }

}
    }
```

ApplicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="com.contgo.CustomResourceBundleMessageSource">  
         <qualifier value="messageSource"/>
        <property name="basename" value="LanguageResources"/>  
</bean>
```

I've tried to add @qualifier("messageSource") as well but doesn't work.
Also try @Resource and @Inject, doesn't work either.

Has anyone ever managed to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and finally got it working as follows.
The class extending ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource is correct.
All you need to do is configure it properly in your applicationContext file.

You leave the original ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource configuration alone:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource" id="messageSource">  
        <property name="basename" value="LanguageResources"/>  
</bean>
```

Then you add the following below it, using the 'parent' attribute to refer to the original config:

```
<bean class="com.contgo.CustomResourceBundleMessageSource" id="myCustomMessageSource" parent="messageSource"/>
```

Then finally, in your controller you can autowire it like this:

```
@Autowired
CustomResourceBundleMessageSource myCustomMessageSource;
```